# luaLaTeX Junicode font typesetting of ji and ii

Tags: fonts, luatex, ligatures

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}
\begin{document}
\noindent
ji\\
ii\\
j\mbox{}i\\
i\mbox{}i
\end{document}
```

is rendered by lualatex with dotless i on the first two lines.  Does anyone know where this comes from and if it is possible to turn it off somehow?  I've tried to turn ligatures off, but it didn't help, nor can I find ji or ii ligatures in the Junicode font.  The only thing that worked for me is insert empty box in between the two letters and use a macro `\ji` and `\ii` macros, but it an ugly hack.  If I try to cut the text from the lualatex created pdf, the first character is j (or i) and the second is dotless i.

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting things look fine with XeTeX

Comment: Also, works fine with LuaTeX and the default font. So it is the LuaTeX/Junicode combination specifically...

Comment: I can confirm the problem even though I’m using a more recent version of the fonts, downloaded from Sourceforge, rather than the version in the package on CTAN.

Comment: Yeah, works fine with XeTeX, or say LuaLaTeX + another font, e.g. Dejavu Serif.  I'm stuck with luaLaTeX unfortunately, as gregorio uses lua heavily.

Comment: EB Garamond is another freely available font with a wide range of characters, and it’s perfectly appropriate for chant.  You might try that while waiting for Junicode to be fixed.

Comment: I notice that there's a substitution of `i` with `dotlessi` in the font's "single substitution lookup 41", but I don't know exactly what these "single substitutions" are, nor how to turn them on/off with `fontspec`. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. That substitution is activated by the ``calt`` feature (Contextual Alternates), but adding ``Contextuals = Alternate`` or ``Contextuals = NoAlternate`` has no effect in this case.

Comment: I don't know much about opentype fonts but this one has the glyphs in the slots for lowercase i and j set up as accented glyphs composed from dotless variants plus an accent. That strikes me as... odd, to say the least. There seems to be some confusion here somewhere...

Comment: `uni2170` seems to actually be closer to a lowercase i than the lowercase i. (At least it is a single glyph, albeit not intended for use as a letter.)

Comment: At any rate, it's important to submit a bug report at http://sourceforge.net/p/junicode/bugs/.

Comment: The version of Junicode in TeXLive is very old; version 1.002 seems not to have this problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, only a temporary fix that’s too long for a comment.  You can work around the problem by writing a tiny feature file, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,fontspec}
\begin{filecontents*}{juni.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

# fix problem in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220038/7883
feature fixi {
  sub \dotlessi by \i;
} fixi;
\end{filecontents*}
\setmainfont{Junicode}[
  FeatureFile={juni.fea},
  Contextuals=Alternate,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  RawFeature=+fixi]
\begin{document}
\noindent
ji\\
ii
\end{document}
```

(If your version of `fontspec` is not recent, it will want the options to come between `\setmainfont` and `{Junicode}`, not after.)

**Update**

In TeX Live 2016, the fix seems to work more reliably, even with “ij”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "fixi",
    {
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
            dotlessi = "i",
            dotlessj = "j",
        }
    },
    "fixing i and j"
  }
}
\setmainfont{Junicode}[
  Contextuals=Alternate,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  RawFeature=+fixi]
\begin{document}
ji ii ij
\end{document}
```

If you have updated `luaotfload` since February 2017, invoke `\directlua` this way:

```
\directlua
{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
  {
    name = "fixi",
    type = "substitution",
    data =
        {
          dotlessi = "i",
          dotlessj = "j",
        },
  }
}
```

If you do need a dotless i somewhere, use `\addfontfeature{RawFeature=-fixi}`.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately ij apparently is the same problem with the LuaLaTeX and Junicode font combination, and this trick doesn't seem to work for me with
    sub \dotlessj by \j;
nor
    sub \dotlessj by j;

Comment: Actually
    sub uniF6BE by j;
helps even for the ij case, dunno why it decides to substitute ij for i with a private area j character as opposed to dotless j.

Comment: @JakubJelinek `sub \dotlessi \dotlessj by \ij;`  doesn’t work either.  That’s bizarre, and as Sverre said, it’s time to report the bug.  The problem is not with `luatex`, since other fonts don’t behave this way, and it’s not with the CTAN package, which I’m not using.  You can link to this question in your bug report.

Comment: I've so far posted it to Junicode forum, at
https://sourceforge.net/p/junicode/discussion/534856/thread/985f24af/
as I'm not sure if it is not intentional (but it is strange in any case).

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but still ...

Junicode contains a ccmp lookup that decomposes i to dotlessi when it is followed by a combining diacritical mark (or preceded or followed by a combining double diacritic). This is because the font contains a large number of combining diacritics for which there are no precomposed forms.

It looks to me as if LuaTeX is mistakenly applying this feature even though the context does not require it--though only when a j follows. Why this should be happening is more than I can even begin to imagine. It is an odd intersection of an unusual feature in Junicode and a bug in LuaTeX (I have not seen this bug in any other application).

I do not intend to remove this feature from Junicode. If you have FontForge or another font editor, though, you can do so yourself. It's the third ccmp lookup. Meanwhile, I'm looking for a way to implement Junicode's feature that does not trigger a LuaTeX bug.

Comment: Welcome (back!) to TeX.SE. I assume you are the same user as "P. Baker", who (according to the site information) was last "seen Nov 17 '12 at 18:20". If that's correct, you may want to contact the site administrators to merge the two accounts.

Comment: Might I also suggest you submit a [bug report](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues). `luaotfload` is quite buggy, but the more bugs they hear of, the more of them they can (hopefully) fix.

Comment: Thanks, Mico. I'd forgotten that I had a StackExchange account. I'll get them merged. Sverre: I'm noticing quite a number of LuaTeX bugs, and I'll try to get them organized to submit. My fonts contain lots of OpenType features, and they are good for stress-testing OT engines.

Comment: You can use the @ to ping users you want notified, e.g. @Mico

Comment: Wow, getting your observations on bugs in Lua(La)TeX and especially `luaotfload` -- the utility that performs most of the font-related chores -- will be very useful!